# How do i remove NONREF from my CSV file output, so when the script runs the row is not printed out?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I will like to delete a row from my CSV file output, the output result has a row "NONREF". i do not want the row NONREF to be included in my output.

This is my current CSV file output.

```
Account number (preferred / formatted),Customer reference,Posting date,Account currency,Transaction amount

750-85665-3 0000NONREF 09052019000000104519
750-85665-3 0000233416 0906201900000047765
750-85665-3 0000233425 09062019000000129305
750-85665-3 0000NONREF 0906201900000017707
750-85665-3 0000233421 09092019000000199722
750-85665-3 0000NONREF 09092019000000199722
750-85665-3 0000219838 0910201900000026502
750-85665-3 0000233415 0910201900000016914
750-85665-3 0000NONREF 09102019000000195642
750-85665-3 0000233419 0911201900000099291
```

code tried is:

```
   awk '
   BEGIN{
    FS=","
    }
   FNR==1{
   print
   next
   }
   {
    $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
    $2="0000"$2
    split($3,array,"/")
     $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],array[3])
     gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
     $3=$3"000000"$NF
    print $1,$2,$3
   }
    ' Input_file
```

i want my output without the NONREF rows.

```
750-85665-3 0000233452 09162019000000323724
750-85665-3 0000233441 09162019000000190742
750-85665-3 0000233446 09162019000000230644
750-85665-3 0000233435 09162019000000173321
750-85665-3 0000233442 09162019000000219319
750-85665-3 0000233443 0916201900000097416
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
 }
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
$2!~/NONREF/{
  $1=substr($1,1,3)"-"substr($1,4,5)"-"substr($1,length($1))
  $2="0000"$2
  split($3,array,"/")
  $3=sprintf("%02d%02d%s",array[2],array[1],array[3])
  gsub(/^-|\./,"",$NF)
  $3=$3"000000"$NF
  print $1,$2,$3
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thankyou very much you have been very help. i so much appreciate the help. do you have a website or a page. i will like to learn more scripting from you?

Comment: @jaybiano, Glad that I could help you :) To be honest I learnt it from this great community SO, see this page once https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info you will get GREAT information from basic info to books, posts etc etc  you could definetly start from here and could post your questions whenever and wherever you get stuck. Stack overflow is a GREAT place to learn, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: i can you look at this please, the script prints this output            
750-85665-3 0000233435  09162019000000173321
750-85665-3 0000233442  09162019000000219319
750-85665-3 0000233443  0916201900000097416
750-85665-3 0000233439  0916201900000019992
My desired output: 750-85665-3  0000233453 091719000000087196
750-85665-3  0000233437 091719000000047765
750-85665-3  0000233429 091819000000069263
750-85665-3  0000233448 091819000000069263

Comment: the last column should have 18 digits but with my output some has 18 digits while some has less, when it is less i want it filled with zeroes to make it 18 digits to match format

Comment: @jaybiano,I am sorry but honestly I didn't understand where is the problem, could you please wrap up samples in back ticks as it doesn't look clear.

Comment: My OUTPUT:                                                                                                                 
750-85665-3 0000233448  0918201900000069263
750-85665-3 0000233434  0920201900000015199
750-85665-3 0000233447  092320190000006619
750-85665-3 0000233450  092320190000001461
Desired OUTPUT:                                                                                                     750-85665-3  0000233436 093019000000169141
750-85665-3  0000233440 093019000000099289
750-85665-3  0000233459 093019000000391856

Comment: the last 3 columns merged together to become one  were suppose to have 18 digits.

Comment: @jaybiano, could you please EDIT your post with correct comma separated input values and correct sample expected output  and let me know then?

Comment: @jaybiano, Sorry but I am really confuse now :)

Comment: i am creating a new question and will send you link so you get a clearer picture @RavinderSingh13